# Emacs: one-line comments every time, everywhere

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like an interactive function that would comment-or-uncomment *region* using **only the one-line comment** syntax of the mode.

Currently, in PHP, when I comment out (using either `comment-or-uncomment-region` or `comment-dwim`)

```
This
Block of
Code
```

I get this:

```
/* 
 * This
 * Block of
 * Code
 */
```

But what I need is this:

```
// This
// Block of
// Code
```

I tried to (no, let me rephrase this: I spent nights trying every possible combination) use `M-x customize-group RET comment`, specifically the variables `comment-multi-line` and `comment-style` but to no avail.

Note that when I edit Javascript, js-mode does exactly that. How can I get this behaviour in **all** modes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```el
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'my-php-mode-hook)
(defun my-php-mode-hook ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-start) "//")
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-padding) " ")
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-end) "")
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-style) 'indent))
```

In Emacs 24.3 you can use the form `(setq-local comment-start "//")` instead.

Comment: Sir, you just made my day ; +1 for the new `setq-local` syntax.

Comment: The setting of `comment-style` above should not be necessary (it's not necessarily harmful, but it's not part of what yPhil requested, AFAICT).